# Run process when variable is called

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to run code placed inside of `thing.process` upon when I hit the `command.processCommand` object (when i'm looping through all of the commands placed inside of `defined[]`), is there a way I can achieve this? This aforementioned loop will be executed as is such in myproject.py

command.py

```
class Command:
    global defined

    defined = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.description = "This command lacks a description"
        self.args = ""
        self.process = None

        defined.append(self)
```

eightball.py

```
    def processCommand():
        print('hello')

    thing = commands.Command('8ball')
    thing.description = "Gives you a response from the mighty 8ball."
    thing.process = processCommand
```

myproject.py

```
# Cogs
import cogs.commands as commands
import cogs.eightball
import cogs.helloworld

def processCommands(message):
    if(message.content[:2] == "b#"):
        args = message.content.split(' ')

        args[0] = args[0][2:]

        for command in defined:
            if args[0] == command.name:
                command.args = args
                command.processCommand
```

Comment: add `()` to function name to execute it - ie. `thing.process()`

Comment: I should clarify, I don't want to run the command when I import it from the main class.

Comment: you don't have to do it at start but when you need it - you didn't show how/where you want to run it.

Comment: ie. `for x in defined: x.process()` or rather `for x in defined: if x.process: x.process()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in defined: 
    if x.process:  # to skip `self.process = None`
        x.process()
```

---

**EDIT:** you need `process()` instead of `processCommand`

```
    for command in defined:
        if args[0] == command.name:
            command.args = args
            command.process()
```